# Configuring the URL's slug in Nuxtjs3/Directus

Tags: nuxt.js, slug, nuxtjs3, directus

I use **Directx (v9) with Nuxt 3**. The URLs of my test site are based on the principle of **my-collection + post_id**. I.e. if I create a "blog" collection in Directus, then blog posts are displayed on the site as **my-site.com/blog/1** , **my-site.com/blog/2** etc. But I would like to be able to manually create page aliases (slugs). I created a slug (string) field in Directus, and a dynamic page (**pages/blog/[slug].vue**) in Nuxt. But I haven't figured out how to properly configure this to receive data from Directus yet.

I would be grateful if someone could help me figure it out. Sorry for my English!

Comment: Hi, there is no tutorial on how to achieve that from Directus or in any blogpost?

Comment: I didn't find anything anyway. I've seen this done on the Nuxt 3 side, but in my case, I still need a connection with Directus. But if you know where to get this information or you can give a link, I will be grateful to you.

Comment: I've been looking into this as well. I like the way WordPress handles slugs. I found this Directus extension that might do the trick. It allows you to type into your string field and have it automatically converted to proper slug syntax. 

https://github.com/dimitrov-adrian/directus-extension-wpslug-interface

I am not sure this answers your question, though. Is your problem with the Nuxt side or Directus side of things?

Comment: That one looks like the good one to start with: https://directus.io/guides/get-started-building-a-nuxt-3-blog-with-directus/

Comment: @Sean Rasmussen. I have tried this component. It only creates a slug field on the Directus side, the same can be done manually (string field) in Directus. But it doesn't help in URL conversion. I.e. the problem is on the Nuxt side.

Comment: @kissu Yes, I'm just using this starter. I created a test blog with a root category, posts and learned how to display content on the frontend. Now the posts that I create in Directus are displayed on the frontend with addresses like - my-site.com/blog/1 ,  my-site.com/blog/2  etc. And the <script setup> section looks like this:

`const { getItemById } = useDirectusItems();
const route = useRoute();
const post = await getItemById({ collection: "blog", id: route.params.id });`

But I want to find a way to create a URL with a custom slug instead of an ID - like my-site.com/blog/my-post.

Comment: You can create an alias on Nuxt's side but I would definitely solve that on Directus. If you have your thing working well there with a slug, you only need to fetch it and add that as the name of the dynamic page. Can't you replace `/blog/1` with `/blog/my-post` there?

Comment: **@kissu** Yes, I created an alias (slug) on the Directus side. It is passed by the backend in a JSON array along with title, content, image, etc. But I can't replace **/blog/1** with **/blog/my-post** on the Nuxt side yet. That's my question.

Comment: Then, how are you creating your dynamic routes? Did you followed that one? https://v3.nuxtjs.org/guide/directory-structure/pages#dynamic-routes If you have the slug on the backend, you can totally create it as an URL for Nuxt.

Comment: **@kissu** I have the "next-directus" module installed in Nuxt to communicate with the backend. This determines the configuration method. Now in <script setup> I have this construction: `const { getItemById } = useDirectusItems(); const route = useRoute(); const post = await getItemById({ collection: "blog", id: route.params.id });` And so the URLs are displayed as `/blog/1` . But I have to replace ID with slug according to their method `https://nuxt-directus.netlify.app`. In the chat, I was advised to use a filter. But I haven't figured out how to do it yet.